# robot framework how to know if a checkbox is selected

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am using robot framework. How can I test if a checkbox is selected?
I want to run a keyword if a checkbox is selected like:

```
 ${checked} =   Checkbox Should Not Be Selected  xpath=.//*[@id='0,1,1,6']/td[11]/input
    Run Keyword if  '${checked}'  Click Element  xpath=.//*[@id='0,1,1,6']/td[11]/input  and wait
```

i.e. to click there if is not already clicked.

(The code of above is wrong, I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a bit of a hack, you could create a keyword "Is Checked" which first sets a test case level variable to False, then runs "Checkbox should be checked" before setting that variable to True. You can then run this keyword ignoring failure, and check the value of the variable after.
A second, less hacky way would to create this keyword in python, using something like this:

```
def is_checked(locator):
     try:
         selenium.should_be_checked(locator)
     except AssertionError:
         return False
     else:
         return True
```

although you'll need to verify what exception is raised by "should be checked" and also you'll need to look at robotframework.libraries.Built In to see how to access the current running selenium library instance